# drawing graphical models / bayesnet

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw something like this 
[image]

The closest I have come is with this code, which uses the bayesnet package

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{bayesnet}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \tikz{
% nodes
 \node[obs] (x) {$x$};%
 \node[latent,above=of x,xshift=-1cm,fill] (y) {$y$}; %
 \node[latent,above=of x,xshift=1cm] (z) {$z$}; %
 \draw (0,1.69) circle(.36cm);
% plate
 \plate [inner sep=.25cm,yshift=.2cm] {plate1} {(x)(y)(z)} {$N$}; %
% edges
 \edge {y,z} {x}  }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But I cannot get the half-filled circle as the one for y. The advantage with bayesnet is that it is relatively easy to draw different graphical models, so I am trying to find a solution usingt bayesnet (if possible).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know `bayesnet` so I've provided a solution with `path picture`. It fills a rectangle inside the node clipped by the real node's border.

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{bayesnet}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}


\begin{document}

%\begin{figure}
  \tikz{
% nodes
 \node[obs] (x) {$x$};%
 \node[latent,above=of x,xshift=-1cm,path picture={\fill[gray!25] (path picture bounding box.south) rectangle (path picture bounding box.north west);}] (y) {$y$}; %
 \node[latent,above=of x,xshift=1cm] (z) {$z$}; %
 \draw (0,1.69) circle(.36cm);
% plate
 \plate [inner sep=.25cm,yshift=.2cm] {plate1} {(x)(y)(z)} {$N$}; %
% edges
 \edge {y,z} {x}  }
%\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! could you explain me how path picture works? I mean the inputs you have used, so I can use the same approach in other diagrams

Comment: @user1571823 Please read section [15.6 Generalized Filling: Using Arbitrary Pictures to Fill a Path](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgf#page=173) in pgfmanual. Basically with `path picture` you can use whatever you want to fill a node but the result is clipped by node's border.

Comment: I adding also +1 for your excellent work.